# ant fresh_install - Error

Tags: ant

I am not a code writer or technical guy. Trying to install Dspace with the guides provided. I am stucked in ant fresh_insatll process and here is the error message. Can someone help to overcome this.

Buildfile: C:\dspace-6.0-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\build.xml

init_installation:

```
prepare_configs:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\dspace-6.0-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 156 files to C:\dspace-6.0-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\dspace-6.0-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp
     [copy] Copying 16 files to C:\dspace-6.0-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp

init_configs:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\dspace\config
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\dspace-6.0-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-installer\config-temp

test_database:
     [java] 2016-11-08 07:17:42,129 WARN  org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder @ Internal error
     [java] org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source local.cfg
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:259)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:238)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder$FileConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:1455)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder$ConfigurationBeanFactory.createBean(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:1321)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:390)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:412)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:426)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.createConfigurationAt(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:855)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.initCombinedConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:719)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:622)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:587)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.loadInitialConfig(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:494)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.config.DSpaceConfigurationService.<init>(DSpaceConfigurationService.java:87)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:148)
     [java]     at org.dspace.servicemanager.DSpaceKernelImpl.start(DSpaceKernelImpl.java:128)
     [java]     at org.dspace.app.launcher.ScriptLauncher.main(ScriptLauncher.java:49)
     [java] 2016-11-08 07:17:44,969 WARN  org.dspace.services.email.EmailServiceImpl @ Couldn't get an email session from environment:  Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
     [java] 
     [java] Attempting to connect to database
     [java] Connected successfully!
     [java] 
     [java] Database Type: postgres
     [java] Database URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dspace
     [java] Database Schema: public
     [java] Database Username: dspace
     [java] Database Software: PostgreSQL version 9.6.1
     [java] Database Driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver version PostgreSQL 9.4.1211
     [java] PostgreSQL 'pgcrypto' extension installed/up-to-date? false (not installed)
     [java] 
     [java] WARNING: Required PostgreSQL 'pgcrypto' extension is NOT INSTALLED on this database.
     [java] 
     [java] ** DSpace REQUIRES PostgreSQL >= 9.4 AND pgcrypto extension >= 1.1 **
     [java] 
     [java] To install it, please connect to your DSpace database as a 'superuser' and manually run the following command: 
     [java] 
     [java]   CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
     [java] 
     [java] 2016-11-08 07:17:45,781 WARN  org.dspace.services.sessions.SessionRequestServiceImpl @ Request interceptor (org.dspace.services.events.SystemEventService$EventRequestInterceptor@52fd6efa) failed to execute on end (request-70-1478569665302): null
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled pgcrypto on your new made PostgreSQL database?

```
psql --username=postgres dspace -c "CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;"
```

See DSpace 6.0 manual, paragraph 4. Database Setup: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-Installation